# Parse list of certain Format

Tags: python

I have a list which is in this certain format.

```
[u' ', u'Address :',u'Sadar Bazaar',u'new Delhi,India',u' ',u'Name :',u'Saun-Jean',u' ',u'Occupation :',u'Developer',u'Hacker',u' ']
```

I want to Insert Records into Database.

Here is my thought ,How to do it.

1) Take all items between two `u' '`

2) The second item `u'Address'` defines the field of the Database and rest up-to next `u' '` defines the data.
like

```
 'Address :','Sadar Bazaar','new Delhi,India'
```

3)Repeat this procedure for all Items.

There may be other good ideas.

But i don't know how to do it in Python.Can someone help me do it??

Edit:
Here is how i constructed the List:

```
for tr in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//tbody//tbody//tr"):
 tds=tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
 if tds:
  data.append([td.text for td in tds])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lis=[u' ', u'Address :',u'Sadar Bazaar',u'new Delhi,India',u' ',u'Name :',u'Saun-Jean',u' ',u'Occupation :',u'Developer',u'Hacker',u' ']
strs=' '.join(str(x).strip() for x in lis if str(x).strip())
lis1=strs.split(':')
dic={}
for i,x in enumerate(lis1[:-1]):
    if x.strip():
        temp_lis=x.strip().split()
        if i+1 <len(lis1)-1:
            dic[temp_lis[-1]]=' '.join(lis1[i+1].split()[:-1])
        else:
            dic[temp_lis[-1]]=' '.join(lis1[i+1].split())

print dic
```

**output:**

```
{'Occupation': 'Developer Hacker', 'Name': 'Saun-Jean', 'Address': 'Sadar Bazaar new Delhi,India'}
```

Comment: The code is fine but there is one problem.if list is like `u' Last Name :'` it only picks Name: and cuts off Last .Is there any solution to it??

Comment: my code relies on the fact that there's no space between the keys, you can use `Last-Name`, then it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is much better done as a dictionary:

```
d={}
d['Address'] = ['sadar bazaar', ...]
d['Name'] = [ 'saun-jean', ... ]
...
```

Or perhaps as a list of dictionaries (or class instances):

```
[ {'Address' : 'sadar bazaar', 'Name': 'saun-jean'}, { ... } ]
```

To convert your list into a list of dictionaries like I have above, you can do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
a = iter(yourlist)
key = None
for elem in a:
   if elem == u' ':
      key = next(a)
   else:
      d[key].append(elem)
```

Comment: But if there are multiple records like this. how would i do it automatically.Here now you are manually assigning the values to the dict

Comment: @saunjean -- How did you build the list initially?  If we know that, then I can instruct you on how to build it as a `dict`.

Comment: I extracted it from a Webpage.

Comment: From the webpage, how did you get it into the form you now have?  (with the blank spaces in between record IDs?)

Comment: @saunjean he's done `d['Address'] = ...` to show you what it would look like but you could just as easily do it with a variable like (excuse inline code in comment) `x = 'Address'` `d[x] = ...`, and thus can set x however you need to...

Comment: @saunjean -- the code you posted won't give the list you posted.  The code you posted will give a list which contains more lists, but that isn't what you said you have.

Comment: @mgilson You are correct but i just took one list which has the data i have posted and i am interested in that list only

Comment: @saunjean -- I've added code which should convert your list into a dictionary of lists.

Comment: @mgilson I tried your code and it is giving  `Error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
StopIteration`

Answer (score 0):

You have to construct dictionary at first place, that could be done by doing something like this(rough code):

```
data = {'Adress' : '',
        'Name' : '',
        'Occupation' : ''}
for item in tds:
    data['Adress'] = item[0]
    data['Name'] = item[1]
    data['Occupation'] = item[2]
```

ofcourse this is in case that trs in tds are always at the same place. 
And then you can use the "data" dictionary to pull data by name

Answer (score 0):

Using your data as is:

```
l = [u' ', u'Address :',u'Sadar Bazaar',u'new Delhi,India',u' ',u'Name :',u'Saun-Jean',u' ',u'Occupation :',u'Developer',u'Hacker',u' ']

entries = {}
key = ''
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == u' ' and i + 1 < len(l):
        key = l[i + 1].replace(':', '').strip()
        entries[key] = []
    elif entries.has_key(l[i].replace(':', '').strip()):
        continue
    else:
        # remove trailing space
        if l[i] != u' ':
            entries[key].append(l[i])

print entries
```

Outputs as a Dictionary:

```
{u'Occupation': [u'Developer', u'Hacker'], u'Name': [u'Saun-Jean'], u'Address': [u'Sadar Bazaar', u'new Delhi,India']}
```

Comment: I copy/pasted the code from above into my python interpreter and received no errors.